# Pyspark rdd filter duplicate

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have this rdd

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(['101,2020-09-04', 30.4, 0.0, 0.0], ['101,2020-09-04', 29.5, 45, 0.0], ['102,2020-09-04', 45.2, 48, 0.0])
```

I am new to python and pyspark, I am trying to solve this using RDD way only, I know the solution using dataframe way but need this only using rdd way.
I am trying to filter duplicate on basis of counting occurrence of 0.0 in single tuple/row.
means first tuple '101,2020-09-04' has 2 times 0.0 and second tuple has 0nly 1 time 0.0 So i want to pick second tuple here.

my expected output is:

```
[['101,2020-09-04', 29.5, 45, 0.0], ['102,2020-09-04', 45.2, 48, 0.0]]
```

Also do not want to count 0.0 for every tuple, count only if id is duplicate.

Comment: anyone ? please guide me on this

Comment: Take a look at the answer I posted. I think it addresses your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's work through this.

```py
# First we set up the problem
data = [['101,2020-09-04', 30.4, 0.0, 0.0], ['101,2020-09-04', 29.5, 45, 0.0], ['102,2020-09-04', 45.2, 48, 0.0]]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

# Break RDD rows into pairs: the common part to serve as our key, and the rest of the list
pair_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1:]))
pair_rdd.collect()
#[('101,2020-09-04', [30.4, 0.0, 0.0]), ('101,2020-09-04', [29.5, 45, 0.0]), ('102,2020-09-04', [45.2, 48, 0.0])]
```

Now that the common part is separated we can use it to `reduceByKey`, but first we need a function that will compare the list values.

```py
# Comparing lists e.g. [1,0] > [0,1] -> True, because it compares elements 
# left to right. We reverse the lists in the function, so that the 
# zeros are on the left most side
# [0.0, 0.0, 30.4] < [0.0, 45, 29.5] -> True
def get_most_complete(record1, record2):
  if (record1[::-1] > record2[::-1]):
    return record1
  else:
    return record2

# Now we have our function and can reduceByKey
reduced_pair_rdd = pair_rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: get_most_complete(x,y))

# Then we dismantle the pair into its original form
result = reduced_pair_rdd.map(lambda x: [x[0]] + x[1])
result.collect()
#[['101,2020-09-04', 29.5, 45, 0.0], ['102,2020-09-04', 45.2, 48, 0.0]]
```

And that's the result you wanted.